# Dask: cannot safely cast non-equivalent float64 to int64 but with only object and int64 columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dask

I Try to read and work on a CSV with 60 columns (150MB) doing:

```
 df = dataframe.read_csv(
            path,
            **dialect,
            dtype=dtype,
            encoding=encoding,
            storage_options=storage_options,
        )
```

but when i try something `len(df)`, it raises a `TypeError: cannot safely cast non-equivalent float64 to int64`

But, in `dtype` I only have specified `Int64` and `object` types for my columns definition.

Where does this float conversion comes from?

EDIT: After investigation, the problem is related to a column defined as int which contains (far away in the CSV) some string values. The error is clearly not explicit

EDIT: Stacktrace

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/benjamin/try/try-back/apps/data/tasks.py", line 168, in csv_to_parquet_task
    df.to_parquet(
  File "/home/benjamin/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/try-dKznE2K2-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dask/dataframe/core.py", line 3974, in to_parquet
    return to_parquet(self, path, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/benjamin/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/try-dKznE2K2-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dask/dataframe/io/parquet/core.py", line 508, in to_parquet
    out = out.compute(**compute_kwargs)
  File "/home/benjamin/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/try-dKznE2K2-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dask/base.py", line 167, in compute
    (result,) = compute(self, traverse=False, **kwargs)
  File "/home/benjamin/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/try-dKznE2K2-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dask/base.py", line 452, in compute
    results = schedule(dsk, keys, **kwargs)
  File "/home/benjamin/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/try-dKznE2K2-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dask/threaded.py", line 76, in get
    results = get_async(
  File "/home/benjamin/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/try-dKznE2K2-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dask/local.py", line 486, in get_async
    raise_exception(exc, tb)
  File "/home/benjamin/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/try-dKznE2K2-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dask/local.py", line 316, in reraise
    raise exc
  File "/home/benjamin/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/try-dKznE2K2-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dask/local.py", line 222, in execute_task
    result = _execute_task(task, data)
  File "/home/benjamin/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/try-dKznE2K2-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dask/core.py", line 121, in _execute_task
    return func(*(_execute_task(a, cache) for a in args))
  File "/home/benjamin/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/try-dKznE2K2-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dask/core.py", line 121, in <genexpr>
    return func(*(_execute_task(a, cache) for a in args))
  File "/home/benjamin/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/try-dKznE2K2-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dask/core.py", line 121, in _execute_task
    return func(*(_execute_task(a, cache) for a in args))
  File "/home/benjamin/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/try-dKznE2K2-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dask/dataframe/io/csv.py", line 150, in pandas_read_text
    df = reader(bio, **kwargs)
  File "/home/benjamin/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/try-dKznE2K2-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 688, in read_csv
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "/home/benjamin/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/try-dKznE2K2-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 460, in _read
    data = parser.read(nrows)
  File "/home/benjamin/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/try-dKznE2K2-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1198, in read
    ret = self._engine.read(nrows)
  File "/home/benjamin/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/try-dKznE2K2-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 2157, in read
    data = self._reader.read(nrows)
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 847, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 862, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_low_memory
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 941, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 1073, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_column_data
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 1104, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_tokens
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 1182, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_with_dtype
  File "/home/benjamin/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/try-dKznE2K2-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/arrays/integer.py", line 385, in _from_sequence_of_strings
    return cls._from_sequence(scalars, dtype, copy)
  File "/home/benjamin/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/try-dKznE2K2-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/arrays/integer.py", line 378, in _from_sequence
    return integer_array(scalars, dtype=dtype, copy=copy)
  File "/home/benjamin/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/try-dKznE2K2-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/arrays/integer.py", line 160, in integer_array
    values, mask = coerce_to_array(values, dtype=dtype, copy=copy)
  File "/home/benjamin/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/try-dKznE2K2-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/arrays/integer.py", line 275, in coerce_to_array
    values = safe_cast(values, dtype, copy=False)
  File "/home/benjamin/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/try-dKznE2K2-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/arrays/integer.py", line 179, in safe_cast
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: cannot safely cast non-equivalent float64 to int64
```

Comment: propably you have NaNs there, try to fill them before

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]. If you are getting an error, post *the full error message including the stack trace*

Comment: By NaNs you mean empty values or something else like "NaN" ?

Comment: You aren't getting this error from `len(df)`, you are getting it from `df.to_parquet`.

Comment: Yes but i simplified the problem with a len(df) because it is note related to parquet but to the type and the content.

Comment: EDIT added in question I think i found something